# Android Service desstroyed and stop automatically without calling stopService() or stopSelf

Tags: android

I have spend like 2 hours,
 I'm unable to figure out what is the issue in service. I'm not calling stopService() or stopSelf from anywhere else. Below is the code ,

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service {

private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private View mFloatingView;


 WindowManager.LayoutParams params,landscapeParams,nonTouchableParams;

public FloatingViewService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Inflate the floating view layout we created
    mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_widget, null);

    //Add the view to the window.
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    //Specify the view position
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;



    //Add the view to the window.
    landscapeParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    //Specify the view position
    landscapeParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
    landscapeParams.x = 0;
    landscapeParams.y = 100;

    //Add the view to the window.
    nonTouchableParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    //Specify the view position
    nonTouchableParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
    nonTouchableParams.x = 0;
    nonTouchableParams.y = 100;

    //Add the view to the window
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);

    //The root element of the collapsed view layout
    final View collapsedView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view);
    //The root element of the expanded view layout
    final View expandedView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_container);


    //Set the close button
    ImageView closeButtonCollapsed = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
    closeButtonCollapsed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //close the service and remove the from from the window
            stopSelf();
        }
    });


    //Set the close button
    ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    //Set the close button
    ImageView lock = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.lock_button);
    lock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, nonTouchableParams);

        }
    });

    //Set the close button
    ImageView expand = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.expand);
    expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, landscapeParams);

        }
    });



    //Drag and move floating view using user's touch action.
    mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.root_container).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    //remember the initial position.
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;

                    //get the touch location
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    int Xdiff = (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    int Ydiff = (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                    //The check for Xdiff <10 && YDiff< 10 because sometime elements moves a little while clicking.
                    //So that is click event.
                    if (Xdiff < 10 && Ydiff < 10) {
                        if (isViewCollapsed()) {
                            //When user clicks on the image view of the collapsed layout,
                            //visibility of the collapsed layout will be changed to "View.GONE"
                            //and expanded view will become visible.
                            collapsedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            expandedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                    //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Detect if the floating view is collapsed or expanded.
 *
 * @return true if the floating view is collapsed.
 */
private boolean isViewCollapsed() {
    return mFloatingView == null || mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mFloatingView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingView);
}
```

}

I am not able to figure out anomalous behaviour help me out.

Comment: Are you seeing any crashes or errors in the log?

Comment: No. I'm seeing nothing in logcat.

Comment: Probably your process was terminated.

Comment: Actually it sounds stupid but  I'm getting this situation only when I open clash of clans game. I thought It might be landscape mode. But for other apps it works fine. Can't figure out issue :\

Comment: No, App is running in the background @CommonsWare.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I put log statement in onStartCommand() I think service is getting restarted. I'm putting some extras while starting Service. And whenever It restarts I'm getting null intent. Still I'm not getting why service is stopping and restarting automatically. @CommonsWare

Comment: "Still I'm not getting why service is stopping and restarting automatically" -- as I wrote, probably your process was terminated. The default `onStartCommand()` return value is `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`, IIRC, and so after Android terminates your process, it will later restart it. Your question does not explain your symptoms. If your symptoms are "why is this floating window thingy going away?", then you need to figure out why `onCreate()` is not doing its work on the second invocation. Also, bear in mind that I think these floating-window apps will not work on Android O.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your support your every word let us learn more. Thank you. I must run that service in foreground.

Comment: you shouldn't be worring about updating the UI from the service... it goes against Android principles... limit the service to process information only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your service as forground.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)

Comment: I'll try it out.

Comment: return "lots of thaks";

Comment: And yeah also think of return value from onSartCommand() .   You are welcome.

Comment: Yeah that was fruitful discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your service to run continuously you will have to override the `onStartCommand` method and return `START_STICKY`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   return START_STICKY;
}
```

> For started services, there are two additional major modes of operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they return from onStartCommand(): START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them. See the linked documentation for more detail on the semantics.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: No, START_STICKY just returns null intent value whenever service restarts automatically. But why service is restarting? any idea? @Nate

Comment: Android framework is responsible for that. It maintains a priority stack to kill components whenever low memory is there and restarts them accordingly when memory is available.

Comment: It helps @mnp343 but How should I avoid it?

Comment: How are you starting the service?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification).      This might help

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(FulllScreenImageView.this, FloatingViewService.class); startService(intent)